# Create extension for Postgres 11 results in "could not access file $libdir/..."

Tags: c, postgresql, docker

I try to follow [this](https://dzone.com/articles/postgresql-simple-c-extension-development-for-a-no) simple example. So, I created a folder addme with four files. Makerfile looks like:

```
MODULES = addme
EXTENSION = addme
DATA = addme--0.0.1.sql
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

addme.control file looks as

```
comment = 'Simple number add function'
default_version = '0.0.1'
relocatable = true
module_pathname = '$libdir/addme'
```

addme.c is as simple as:

```
#include "postgres.h"

#include "fmgr.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(addme);

Datum addme(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int32 arg1 = PG_GETARG_INT32(0);
    int32 arg2 = PG_GETARG_INT32(1);
    PG_RETURN_INT32(arg1 + arg2);
}
```

And finally addme--0.0.1.sql looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION

addme(int, int) RETURNS int AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME','addme'

LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Inside docker I install Postgres 11 and all necessary libraries and dependencies:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
....
....
RUN ... apt-get install -y postgresql-11 postgresql-client-11 postgresql-contrib-11
```

`postgresql-server-dev-all` and `postgresql-common` are also installed. And PATH is set like so:

```
ENV PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin:${PATH}"
```

Besides, I compile `addme` extension like so:

```
RUN cd /usr/src/addme && \
make clean && make PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config && make install PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config && \
cp ./addme.control /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/addme.control && \
cp ./addme--0.0.1.sql /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/addme--0.0.1.sql && \
cp ./addme.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/addme.o && \
cp ./addme.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/addme.so
```

Everything looks good. I build and run the container, I see that Postgres is working and I can list its databases and so forth and so on. However, when I try to create extension `addme`, I get an error. This is a complete stacktrace from inside docker shell:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker exec -it 7e9f9c331351 /bin/bash
root@7e9f9c331351:/# su postgres
postgres@7e9f9c331351:/$ psql
psql (11.6 (Ubuntu 11.6-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# create extension addme;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/addme": No such file or directory
test=# \q
postgres@7e9f9c331351:/$ pg_config --libdir
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
postgres@7e9f9c331351:/$ ls /usr/src/addme
addme--0.0.1.sql  addme.bc  addme.c  addme.control  addme.o  addme.so  Makefile
postgres@7e9f9c331351:/$ cd /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/
postgres@7e9f9c331351:/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension$ find . -name "addme*"
./addme--0.0.1.sql
./addme.control
```

As you can see, it can not find "$libdir/addme". But the catch is $libdir is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `addme.o` and `addme.so` are there. So, what is wrong with that and how can I fix it? Many thanks in advance!

PS. This is my Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV OS_LOCALE="en_US.UTF-8" \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && locale-gen ${OS_LOCALE}
ENV LANG=${OS_LOCALE} \
    LANGUAGE=${OS_LOCALE} \
    LC_ALL=${OS_LOCALE} \
    PG_VERSION=11 \
    PG_USER=postgres \
    PG_HOME=/var/lib/postgresql \
    PG_RUN_DIR=/run/postgresql \
    PG_LOG_DIR=/var/log/postgresql \
    PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin:${PATH}"

ENV PG_CONF_DIR="/etc/postgresql/${PG_VERSION}/main" \
    PG_BIN_DIR="/usr/lib/postgresql/${PG_VERSION}/bin" \
    PG_DATA_DIR="${PG_HOME}/${PG_VERSION}/main"

# Install basic libraries

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc \
    libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler \
    git build-essential \
    wget checkinstall zlib1g-dev \
    make automake autoconf cmake

# Install Postgresql

RUN dpkg-reconfigure locales && apt-get install -y sudo gnupg \
 && wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
 && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y postgresql-${PG_VERSION} postgresql-client-${PG_VERSION} postgresql-contrib-${PG_VERSION} lbzip2 \
 # Cleaning
 && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gnupg \
 && rm -rf ${PG_HOME} \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && touch /tmp/.EMPTY_DB

COPY entrypoint.sh /sbin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /sbin/entrypoint.sh

# Install Postgresql Rabbitmq extension

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python-psycopg2 libpq-dev \
    postgresql-server-dev-all postgresql-common && \
    mkdir /usr/src/addme

COPY ./addme /usr/src/addme

#RUN cd /usr/src/addme && \
#    make clean && make PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config && make install PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config && \
#    cp ./addme.control /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/addme.control && \
#    cp ./addme--0.0.1.sql /usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/addme--0.0.1.sql && \
#    cp ./addme.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/addme.o && \
#    cp ./addme.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/addme.so 

RUN cd /usr/src/addme && \
    make && make install

EXPOSE 5432/tcp
VOLUME ["${PG_HOME}", "${PG_RUN_DIR}"]
CMD ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

It uses entrypoint.sh, which I've taken from [here](https://github.com/romeOz/docker-postgresql/blob/master/11/entrypoint.sh). And I build and run Docker using docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres_db:
    build: ./Database
    environment:
      - DB_USER=test
      - DB_NAME=test
      - DB_PASS=test
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql"
```

So, my folder structure eventually looks like so:

- docker-compose.yml
- Database

  - Dockerfile
  - entrypoint.sh
  - addme

    - addme--0.0.1.sql
    - addme.c
    - addme.control
    - Makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the shared library `addme.so` in the wrong place.

It should be installed in the PostgreSQL library directory, not in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. The PostgreSQL library directory can be found with

```
pg_config --libdir
```

and is probably `/usr/share/postgresql/11/lib`.

To avoid problems like this, it is recommended that you use `make install` rather than manually copying files around.

Comment: Please, have a look at my log from Docker shell. I run there `pg_config --libdir` and it returns `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Then you are calling the wrong `pg_config`. Try `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_config`.

Comment: I will do simple `make install` and will report back. I think I also tried it this way and got other error messages, like `addme.control` is not found etc.

Comment: I've just tried `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_config` and it returned the same `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Actually, I can provide the whole Dockerfile which totally reproduces all errors.

Comment: @Jacobian it would be helpfull.

Comment: UPS! It started working with simple make install. Laurenz was right!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In postgres 11 `pg_config --libdir` returns exactly `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but the answer says that this is can not be the library directory.

Comment: If that were true, `make install` would install the shared library there. Maybe there is more than one PostgreSQL v11 installed? Try to find all `pg_config`s on the machine. To make your life easier, have as few PostgreSQL installations as possible.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just to be sure, in the vanilla postgres container (based on official postgresql image) with `postgresql-server-dev-11` installed produces the same result as above.

Comment: That may be so. Perhaps that PostgreSQL was configured to choose that library directory. Obviously you installed another PostgreSQL that had different ideas, and you were suffering from the confusion.